# Calling Twitter API endpoints with Jmeter

Tags: api, rest, authentication, twitter, jmeter

I have created a Twitter-developer account and also a project and an app to be able to invoke web services endpoints.

I would like to know if anyone has ever managed to successfully retrieve expected response from the endpoints, and in that case, what authentication methods is the simplest and most effective to use and in what order?

Thank you for your help and advice

Answer (score 1):

As per [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/overview) the possible methods are in:

- [OAuth 1.0a](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a)
- [OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0)
- [Basic authentication](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/basic-auth)

The latter one is the easiest to implement as all you need to do is to add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and provide your credentials there and JMeter will automatically add the relevant [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header to all your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

More information: [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter)

Comment: But are you sure that it will work with simply having username and password. I remember reading somewhere that the feature would only work for enterprise level projects?

Comment: There should be some kind of information for each request in what kind of authentication mechanisms it supports. But I might be wrong in that its not always the case.

Comment: Basic Auth is only available for some enterprise API endpoints, correct.

Comment: Thank you @AndyPiper